# Designing and structuring a multirole ReactJS application

Tags: javascript, architecture, reactjs

I am bulding a web application that talks with some APIs in reactJS.

My app has 4 roles,  admin, master, slave, baby.

Every role can see something more than the others, so the the menus, and the view are slightly different between them.

e.g.

```
The navbar has:

for the admin: 5 buttons
for the master: 4 buttons
for the salve: 3 buttons
for the baby: 2 buttons
```

I wanted to know what is the best practice for structuring this application:

Should I have 4 differents apps? This way the component would be clear, but everytime that I need to implement a new function I have to modify 4 apps.

If this is the only way, how can I call the right app based on the role after the login?

Answer (score 0):

Having four separate apps with a lot of overlapping code/functionality would surely not be the best approach; that would result in a lot of unnecessary repetition.

If the different roles just add/remove small features and functionality, I would just wrap rendering of these elements in conditionals. For example:

```
renderAdminButton: function() {
   ( if this.props.user.role === 'admin' ) {
      return (
         <button />
      );
   }
}
```

This function would then be called inside the parent app/component's `render` function.

However, if you REALLY want to have a separate app for each role, you could conditionally render the app with a function similar to this:

```
renderApp: function() {
   var apps = {
      admin: AdminApp,
      master: MasterApp,
      slave: SlaveApp,
      baby: BabyApp
   };

   return apps[this.props.user.role];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button component check for this.props.hide and return null.

```
    render() {
        if (this.props.hide) {return null;}
        return (
            <button>
                {this.props.btn.text}
            </button>
        );
    }
```

In your parent component include logic for each buttons hide prop.

```
    render() {
        var hideAdminBtn = this.props.appState.userRole != 'admin';
        return (
            <JButton hide={hideAdminBtn} />
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is make each access type as a *prop* so you can render the application based on the type of prop received, ideally at `componentDidMount()`. You can then have a `MasterView` that will receive the prop and decide accordingly which view to render. The code will follow along like this:

```
var MasterView = React.createClass({
  var roleType = this.props.role;
  render: function() {
    if(roleType === 'admin') {
      return (
        <AdminView />
      );
   }
});
```

As for your concern about implementing new features, you should break down you view and logic into simple and reusable components. For example all your access type can share a common `<Header />` and `<Footer />` component as well as `<Profile />` `<Settings />` etc. Mind you these can be further broken down so that when you make a small change in any of the components it will propagate to all your views. Similar principles will apply to your logic as well. Remember to stay **DRY**.

---

**Edit:**

Let's assume that the app is being made for a store. All the data displayed via this portal(indicted by the component's name) are:

```
<EmployeeProfile />
<EmployeeSalary />
<BuyerRecords />
<BalanceSheet />
<Inventory />
<Billing />
```

Now let's define the access level of each roles:

- Admin has access to all the functionalities of the app.
- Master can view all but the employee's salary details.
- Slave has access to buyer's record, inventory and billing.
- Child can only view the inventory and billing sections.

Now, these 6 broad components will be defined and will definitely comprise of multiple components. Just make sure that whenever you feel like a specific part of the view will be used elsewhere, go ahead and make it into a separate component.

Finally, the roles should render like this:

```
var AdminView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
   return ( 
     <div>
        <EmployeeProfile />
        <EmployeeSalary />
        <BuyerRecords />
        <BalanceSheet />
        <Inventory />
        <Billing />
     </div>
   );
  }
});

var MasterView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
   return ( 
     <div>
        <EmployeeProfile />
        <BuyerRecords />
        <BalanceSheet />
        <Inventory />
        <Billing />
     </div>
   );
  }
});


var SlaveView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
   return ( 
     <div>
        <BuyerRecords />
        <BalanceSheet />
        <Billing />
     </div>
   );
  }
});

var ChildView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
   return ( 
     <div>
        <Inventory />
        <Billing />
     </div>
   );
  }
});
```

This way you have 4 parent components handling all the views. They comprise of multiple components and in case a change needs to made, it needs to be done only once and it will reflect in all the roles.

If you decide to have a slightly modified `<Inventory />` for each role, you can choose to render different child components of `<Inventory />` as determined by the role.

Go ahead and have a look at this official [blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) as well. Should help clear any doubts :)

Comment: if I dis understand right, this is basicay the same of having 4 apps. Using you example, I will need 4 differente Header component, 4 Profile .... right?

Comment: No. You will have 4 components, `<AdminView />`, `<MasterView />`, `<SlaveView />` and `<BabyView />` and each of them will have that same Header or Footer component. You just need to write these re-usable components once and include them in any of your parent component like `render: function() { return ( <div><Header /><YourAcessSpecificView /> <Footer /></div> ); } `

Comment: but I have differences even in the header and footer. Every view is composed by a lot of components, and every one have things that a role can see and other not. so I don't think your solution is different to having 4 apps.

Comment: @ciaoben edited the answer, hope this explains the concept better.